# What is pattern for Find Or Create database item?

Tags: c#

If there is one, what is the C# idiom for Find-Or-Create?  Pseudocode:

```
private IEntity FindOrCreateEntity(int id, object properties)
{
    Entity foundEntity = _db.Find(id);
    if (foundEntity == null)
    {
        foundEntity = _db.Create<Entity>(properties);
    }
    return foundEntity;
}
```

I don't like find and create being in the same method.

Comment: Then split them into separate methods.  If your Find method returns null, or some other known value, you can then create the entity instead.

Comment: It differs from ORM to ORM.

Comment: None. That's a bad habit if anything. If you want to create a record conditionally, you can use `INSERT WHERE`. Doing this through an ORM actually differs from ORM to ORM

Comment: What are you really trying to do? The question would make sense eg if you wanted to attach a disconnected object, or if you got a bunch of properties from a POST method and wanted to *INSERT* or *UPDATE* them to the database. Different ORMs support this UPSERT scenario in different ways

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't like find and create being in the same method.

Then don't do it?

You now have a method that takes either an ID of an object to look up, or a bunch of properties to populate a new instance with. That's confusing, to say the least.

What if the caller thinks the ID should return an exisiting record, but it doesn't exist (anymore)? It'll then live on under the assumption it's working on an existing record, while in fact the record does not exist in the databaes yet.

Just let the caller adhere to this pattern:

```
var entity = _repository.Find(id);
if (entity == null)
{
    entity = _repository.Create();
}
```

If anyhting, you can give `IEntity`'s implementation an `IsNew` property, which returns whether `Id == default(TId)`.